# Behaviour of feed operator pipeline

Tags: raku

I'm experimenting with the feed operator using the following code:

```
my $limit=10000000;
my $list=(0,1...4);
sub task($_,$name) {
    say "Start $name on $*THREAD";
    loop ( my $i=0; $i < $limit; $i++ ){};
    say "End $name";
    Nil;
}

sub stage( &code, *@elements --> Seq) {
    map(&code,  @elements);
}

sub feeds() {
    my @results;
    $list
    ==> map ({ task($_, "stage 1"); say( now - ENTER now );$_+1})
    ==> map ({ task($_, "stage 2"); say( now - ENTER now );$_+1})
    ==> stage ({ task($_, "stage 3"); say( now - ENTER now );$_+1}) 
    ==> @results;

    say @results;
}

feeds();
```

- the task sub is just a loop to burn cpu cycles and displays the thread used
- the stage sub is a wrapper around the map sub
- each step of the feed pipeline maps to calling the cpu intensive task and timing it. The result of the map is the input +1

The output when run is:

```
Start stage 1 on Thread<1>(Initial thread)
End stage 1
0.7286811
Start stage 2 on Thread<1>(Initial thread)
End stage 2
0.59053989
Start stage 1 on Thread<1>(Initial thread)
End stage 1
0.5955893
Start stage 2 on Thread<1>(Initial thread)
End stage 2
0.59050998
Start stage 1 on Thread<1>(Initial thread)
End stage 1
0.59472201
Start stage 2 on Thread<1>(Initial thread)
End stage 2
0.5968531
Start stage 1 on Thread<1>(Initial thread)
End stage 1
0.5917188
Start stage 2 on Thread<1>(Initial thread)
End stage 2
0.587358
Start stage 1 on Thread<1>(Initial thread)
End stage 1
0.58689858
Start stage 2 on Thread<1>(Initial thread)
End stage 2
0.59177099
Start stage 3 on Thread<1>(Initial thread)
End stage 3
3.8549498
Start stage 3 on Thread<1>(Initial thread)
End stage 3
3.8560015
Start stage 3 on Thread<1>(Initial thread)
End stage 3
3.77634317
Start stage 3 on Thread<1>(Initial thread)
End stage 3
3.6754558
Start stage 3 on Thread<1>(Initial thread)
End stage 3
3.672909
[3 4 5 6 7]
```

The result in `@result` is correct (The input from `$list` in incremented 3 three times)

The output of the first two stages pulls/alternates but the third stage doesn't execute until the completion of all the input into stage 2

Is there an issue with my wrapper to the map sub causing this behaviour?

Also the time it takes to evaluate in the wrapper is significantly longer than a direct call to map.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would help if you golfed it down. Some things can be eliminated, for instance, the reference to a thread, since it's all running in the same thread. Also, what you are returning is a Seq; probably they are not itemized until they are really needed to, which would be when you arrive to third stage. I would say that's normal Seq behavior.

Comment: I think you want to replace `@elements` with `$elements`

Comment: @ugexe you nailed it. Changing `*@elements` with `*$elements` lets the third stage run instep with the others instead of waiting until they complete. As a  mentioned below, I was attempting to match `map`s signature, which was using a `*@` (at least the doc I found). If you would like to post an answer I will except it. thanks

Comment: @jjmerelo My golf game needs some work! I was rushing out the door when I originally posted. I'll try format my questions better in the future. Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 6):

The slurpy parameter is waiting to consume the entire sequence being passed to it. Consider the difference between:

```
raku -e 'sub foo($) { }; my $items := gather for 1..Inf { say $_ }; foo($items);'
```

```
raku -e 'sub foo(*@) { }; my $items := gather for 1..Inf { say $_ }; foo($items);'
```

The first example will finish, the second one will never finish. Thus you would want to change your stage function to:

```
sub stage( &code, $elements --> Seq) {
    map(&code,  $elements);
}
```

Comment: The reason I used a slurpy was an attempt to match the signature of the `map` sub https://docs.perl6.org/routine/map#class_List. I removed the slurpy and the execution time is now consistent! thanks. However the third stage still does not execute until the first two stages are complete.

Comment: @drclaw Itemization, probably, as I commented above.